# Understanding this unusual Excel VBA range statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've come across this rather unusual Range("DataTable[#All]") syntax in some code:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("DataTable[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("AK1:BQ2"), Unique:=False
```

What does the "[#All]" bit mean? It would normally have just written Range("DataTable"). I know about the [A1] = 10 shortcut syntax (Evaluate) but this is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the article [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e), `#All` is used for the entire table, including column headers, data, and possibly present totals.

Comment: Thanks for that - been programming Excel for years and never come across structured references. You live and learn... Never used Excel tables much either

Comment: Me too. And amazed after started using tables. Still prefer old school solutions, though. Things are easier in tables.

Comment: Structured references were introduced with Excel 2007, when Tables replaced the legacy Lists. Where have you been?

Comment: Hey, you don't know what it means to be old enough to consider 2007 as recent. :)

Comment: Quite - I was writing computer games in 6502 and Z80 assembler in the 80s ;-)